# What does the button with a number next to review mean?

Tags: support

Often, I have a button next to review with a number on it. This number doesn't correlate to the number of posts available for me to review, as I can click on it and find no reviews available. What does this number mean?

[image: Picture of review queue]

Comment: I think it is the number of posts up for review, but it doesn't count posts that you've already seen. So if there are five close votes and no other posts up for review, that number will be 5, but if you've already voted on three of the posts, the queue will only show two posts when you go to the review page because you can't review the same post twice.

Comment: In addition of that, AFAIK, it's only showing total number of available "Suggested Edits"... oh, and also probably cached.

Comment: By the way, you can probably get a better answer for this at meta.stackexchange.com. They may have even answered it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just as Torisuda says, just a indicator of the amount of items that are ready for review. This number tends to be a bit inacurate at times ;)

> This indicator is shown only to moderators and users who've gained access to the moderator tools. As such, it behaves in keeping with the design of those tools:
>
> If you poke around in /tools, you'll quickly notice that most of
>   what's found there isn't directly actionable - it's informational!
>   What you do with that information is up to you: hopefully, you've been
>   around long enough now that you have some idea of how you want the
>   site to be run, and are able to make good use of the information
>   presented.

As quoted from [shog9's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230802/259147) answer on why the number is showing a higher amount then the amount of reviews available

and [The actual request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar)

Comment: It's a pretty useless and distracting feature I would say. Should only show if review queues are overloaded.

Comment: @Gao For smaller sites such as A&M indeed. All though I must say, I also only go to the review queue when the orange thingy pops up. But we could always make a feature request to give it some sort of threshold :)